# Ajax отправляет форму с пустыми обязательными полями

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

При нажатии на ссылку ajax отправляет форму, но с пустыми полями (на полях стоит required)

```js
let a = document.querySelector('.asd');
a.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form_data = $(form).serialize(); // Собираем все данные из формы
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", // Метод отправки
        url: "php/post.php", // Путь до php файла отправителя
        data: form_data,
        success: function () {
            // Код в этом блоке выполняется при успешной отправке сообщения
            alert("Ваше сообщение отправлено!");
        }
    });
})
$("#form").submit(function (e) { // Устанавливаем событие отправки для формы с id=form
   
 });
```

```html
<form id = "form" name="form" class="form" action="php/post.php" method="POST">
                        <input type="text" name="surname" placeholder="Фамилия И.О" required> <br>
                        <input type="text" name="office" placeholder="Отдел (полное название)"required > <br>
                        <select name="printer_model" required>
                            <option value="Kyocera">Kyocera</option>
                            <option value="HP">HP</option>
                            <option value="Cannon">Cannon</option>
                            <option value="Xerox">Xerox</option>
                            <option value="Samsung">Samsung</option>
                        </select><br>
                        <select name="service" id="service" required>
                            <option value="Заправка">Заправка</option>
                            <option value="Ремонт">Ремонт</option>
                            <option value="Очистка">Очистка</option>
                        </select><br>
                        <input type="text" name="number" placeholder="Инвентарный номер"  required> <br>
                         <span><a class="asd" ></a></span>
                    </form>
```

Comment: Разумеется, отправляет: required - это для пользователя. А для формы нужна программная проверка полей и блокировка отправки в случае, если обязательные поля не заполнены. У Вас в коде я такой проверки не вижу.

Comment: var form_data = $(form).serialize(); // Собираем все данные из формы
    if (!form_data.value){
        alert ('Заполните все поля')
        return;
    } else { Написал такую проверку, но теперь он постоянно просит заполнить поля;D

Comment: function checkParams() {
    let surname = document.querySelector('#surname').textContent;
    let aBt = document.querySelector('#sa');
    if (surname.text != '') {
        aBt.classList.remove('disabled');
    } else {
        aBt.classList.add('disabled');
    }
}  Написал данные код для дизейбла кнопки если поле не заполнено. Он удаляет дизейбл когда поле заполнено, но когда оно пустое он не добавляет. Подскажите почему?

Comment: function checkParams() {
    let surname = document.querySelector('#surname');
    let office = document.querySelector('#office');
    let number = document.querySelector('#number');
    let aBt = document.querySelector('#sa');
    if (surname.value != '' && office.value != '' && number.value != '') {
        aBt.classList.remove('disabled');
    } else {
        aBt.classList.add('disabled');
    }
} сделал

Comment: Ну, потому что если disabled уже был убран, то его добавление может произойти только по какому-то событию. Само по себе пустое поле событием не является - нужно какое-то действие (submit, click, keyup и т.д.)

Comment: keyup я установил для формы. Я просто условие не правильно указал, вместо text установил value и все заработало. Вопрос почему required не отображается вообще?

Answer (score 1):

Добавил дизейбл для ссылки, если инпуты пусты.

```js
function checkParams() {
    let surname = document.querySelector('#surname');
    let office = document.querySelector('#office');
    let number = document.querySelector('#number');
    let aBt = document.querySelector('#sa');
    if (surname.value != '' && office.value != '' && number.value != '') {
        aBt.classList.remove('disabled');
    } else {
        aBt.classList.add('disabled');
    }
}
```